# SQL WHERE sub query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-administration

I have a table in MySQL,

```
value tag main_tag
1 tag_A ABC
-1 tag_C ABC
-1 tag_A BCD
1 tag_C BCD
-1 tag_A ABC
1 tag_C ABC
-1 tag_A BCD
1 tag_C BCD
-1 tag_C BCD
```

There are three columns `value`, `tag`, `main_tag`. Under each `main_tag` there are several other `tag` s. I want to get the records where sum of `value` s of each `tag` is equal to zero under each `main_tag`.

This is the query I tried,

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ( WHERE sum(value) = 0 GROUP BY tag) GROUP BY main_tag ;
```

First I am trying to find the sum of values `GROUP BY tag` and then I am using `GROUP BY main_tag`. But it is not working.

Output Should be :

```
value tag main_tag
1 tag_A ABC 
-1 tag_C ABC 
-1 tag_A ABC 
1 tag_C ABC
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: Updated the desired output

Comment: How to see which child tag belongs to which parent tag?  I don't see it with the current data example.. There arent tags called ABC, BCD like the main_tag column suggest.

Comment: 1 tag_A ABC in this line, tag tag_A is under main_tag ABC. There might be identical tag names under each main_tag

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select main_tag
from foo
group by main_tag
having sum(value) = 0;
```

Comment: No, I want to group by BY tag then BY main_tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` clause with `JOIN` :

```
select f.*
from foo f inner join 
           (select distinct tag
            from foo
            group by tag, main_tag
            having sum(value) = 0
          ) f1
          on f1.tag = f.tag;
```

Comment: It returns the same table

Comment: It is not working for a different use case. I have updated the table with more values, please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table temp select 'value', CONCAT('tag','main_tag') 
as group_tag from your_table;

select group_tag
from temp
group by group_tag
having sum(value) = 0;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.